# What CSS term (or page element) am I looking for?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a the term to use when a header element (h1, h2, h3) of sorts stretches across a page with a background.

Something like this:

```
 _______________________________
|         PAGE HEADER           |
|_______________________________|
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
```

I once saw a really cool tutorial where a guy used CSS to make it look like the page title was popping out of the page (used text shadows and other things). I cannot find this tutorial and Google searches are frustrating me because when you look up "page header" you just end up with articles about the html `head` tag.

Is there a certain term for this kind of "banner" that stretches across the top of an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call it an article title, I don't believe there is any jargon for this. I made a quick codepen for you to look at. Hopefully this answers your question! It spans across the top of a the page just like you want it to. I included a 3D-style text too. http://codepen.io/atomicpages/pen/beJFx and you can easily create 3D text using CSS here: [3D Text](http://www.3dcsstext.com/)

Comment: Thanks...I did finally find the effect I was looking for, it was called a Ribbon

Comment: Awesome! Here is another resource if you want it [link](http://www.quickribbon.com/)